# For parametrized functions, can we determine function range directly?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

```
H[t_] = Log[t] - (t - 1)/(λ t + μ)
```

The definition domain and the parameter ranges for the function `H` are:

```
0 < t < 1, μ >= λ > 0
```

But the range of the function `H` cannot be determined directly using the following code:

```
H[t_] = Log[t] - (t - 1)/(λ t + μ)
FunctionRange[{H[t], 0 < t < 1, μ >= λ > 0}, t, y]
```

Comment: Cross-posted at https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3006988.

Answer (score 2):

The limits

```
Limit[-((-1 + t)/(t \[Lambda] + \[Mu])) + Log[t], t -> 0, 
Direction -> "FromAbove",  Assumptions -> \[Mu] >= \[Lambda] && \[Lambda] > 0]
```

> `-Infinity`

```
Limit[-((-1 + t)/(t \[Lambda] + \[Mu])) + Log[t], t -> 1, 
 Direction -> "FromBelow", Assumptions -> \[Mu] >= \[Lambda] && \[Lambda] > 0]
```

> `0`

and the continuity of `-((-1 + t)/(t \[Lambda] + \[Mu])) + Log[t]` on `t>0&&t<1` imply that the range under consideration has the form from minus infinity to some finite real number. In order to find this number, we find the critical point

```
Reduce[D[-((-1 + t)/(t \[Lambda] + \[Mu])) + Log[t], t] == 0 && 
0 < t && t < 1 && \[Mu] >= \[Lambda] > 0, t]
```

> `(0 < \[Mu] < 1/2 && 0 < \[Lambda] <= \[Mu] &&  t == (\[Lambda] + \[Mu] - 2 \[Lambda] \[Mu])/(2 \[Lambda]^2) -  1/2 Sqrt[(\[Lambda]^2 + 2 \[Lambda] \[Mu] -  4 \[Lambda]^2 \[Mu] + \[Mu]^2 -  4 \[Lambda] \[Mu]^2)/\[Lambda]^4]) || (1/2 <= \[Mu] < 1 &&  0 < \[Lambda] < 1 - \[Mu] &&  t == (\[Lambda] + \[Mu] - 2 \[Lambda] \[Mu])/(2 \[Lambda]^2) -  1/2 Sqrt[(\[Lambda]^2 + 2 \[Lambda] \[Mu] -  4 \[Lambda]^2 \[Mu] + \[Mu]^2 -  4 \[Lambda] \[Mu]^2)/\[Lambda]^4])`

It remains to substitute those values in the function, for example,

```
-((-1 + t)/(t \[Lambda] + \[Mu])) + Log[t] /. 
 t -> (\[Lambda] + \[Mu] - 2 \[Lambda] \[Mu])/(2 \[Lambda]^2) - 
   1/2 Sqrt[(\[Lambda]^2 + 2 \[Lambda] \[Mu] - 
 4 \[Lambda]^2 \[Mu] + \[Mu]^2 - 4 \[Lambda] \[Mu]^2)/\[Lambda]^4]
```

If `\[Mu] >= 1`, then there is no critical point. In this case the derivative is positive on `t > 0 && t < 1` as

```
Minimize[{D[-((-1 + t)/(t*\[Lambda] + \[Mu])) + Log[t], t], 
0 < t < 1 && \[Mu] > 1 && \[Lambda] > 0 && \[Lambda] <= \[Mu]}, t]
```

> `{Piecewise[{{(-1 + \[Lambda] + \[Mu])/(\[Lambda] + \[Mu]),  (\[Lambda] > 1 && \[Mu] >= \[Lambda]) ||  (Inequality[0, Less, \[Lambda],  LessEqual, 1] && \[Mu] > 1)}},  Infinity], {t -> Indeterminate}}`

shows. In this case the supremum of `-((-1 + t)/(t \[Lambda] + \[Mu])) + Log[t]` is attained at `t==1` and the one equals zero.

I find preferable the following.

```
range[\[Mu]_?NumericQ, \[Lambda]_?NumericQ] := 
 FunctionRange[{-((-1 + t)/(t \[Lambda] + \[Mu])) + Log[t],  0 < t < 1}, t, y, Reals]

range[Pi/10, E/3]
```

> `y <= 1/2 (60/(3 \[Pi] +  10 E (-((3 (-10 E - 3 \[Pi] + 2 E \[Pi]))/(20 E^2)) - ( 3 Sqrt[100 E^2 + 60 E \[Pi] - 40 E^2 \[Pi] + 9 \[Pi]^2 -  12 E \[Pi]^2])/(20 E^2))) -  90/(E (3 \[Pi] +  10 E (-((3 (-10 E - 3 \[Pi] + 2 E \[Pi]))/(20 E^2)) - (1/( 20 E^2))3 Sqrt[ 100 E^2 + 60 E \[Pi] - 40 E^2 \[Pi] + 9 \[Pi]^2 -  12 E \[Pi]^2]))) - (27 \[Pi])/(E^2 (3 \[Pi] +  10 E (-((3 (-10 E - 3 \[Pi] + 2 E \[Pi]))/(20 E^2)) - (1/( 20 E^2))3 Sqrt[ 100 E^2 + 60 E \[Pi] - 40 E^2 \[Pi] + 9 \[Pi]^2 -  12 E \[Pi]^2]))) + (18 \[Pi])/(E (3 \[Pi] +  10 E (-((3 (-10 E - 3 \[Pi] + 2 E \[Pi]))/(20 E^2)) - (1/( 20 E^2))3 Sqrt[ 100 E^2 + 60 E \[Pi] - 40 E^2 \[Pi] + 9 \[Pi]^2 -  12 E \[Pi]^2]))) + (9 Sqrt[ 100 E^2 + 60 E \[Pi] - 40 E^2 \[Pi] + 9 \[Pi]^2 -  12 E \[Pi]^2])/(E^2 (3 \[Pi] +  10 E (-((3 (-10 E - 3 \[Pi] + 2 E \[Pi]))/(20 E^2)) - (1/( 20 E^2))3 Sqrt[ 100 E^2 + 60 E \[Pi] - 40 E^2 \[Pi] + 9 \[Pi]^2 -  12 E \[Pi]^2]))) + (30 Log[-(( 3 (-10 E - 3 \[Pi] + 2 E \[Pi]))/(20 E^2)) - ( 3 Sqrt[100 E^2 + 60 E \[Pi] - 40 E^2 \[Pi] + 9 \[Pi]^2 -  12 E \[Pi]^2])/(20 E^2)])/(3 \[Pi] +  10 E (-((3 (-10 E - 3 \[Pi] + 2 E \[Pi]))/(20 E^2)) - ( 3 Sqrt[100 E^2 + 60 E \[Pi] - 40 E^2 \[Pi] + 9 \[Pi]^2 -  12 E \[Pi]^2])/(20 E^2))) + (9 \[Pi] Log[-(( 3 (-10 E - 3 \[Pi] + 2 E \[Pi]))/(20 E^2)) - ( 3 Sqrt[100 E^2 + 60 E \[Pi] - 40 E^2 \[Pi] + 9 \[Pi]^2 -  12 E \[Pi]^2])/(20 E^2)])/(E (3 \[Pi] +  10 E (-((3 (-10 E - 3 \[Pi] + 2 E \[Pi]))/(20 E^2)) - (1/( 20 E^2))3 Sqrt[ 100 E^2 + 60 E \[Pi] - 40 E^2 \[Pi] + 9 \[Pi]^2 -  12 E \[Pi]^2]))) - (3 Sqrt[ 100 E^2 + 60 E \[Pi] - 40 E^2 \[Pi] + 9 \[Pi]^2 - 12 E \[Pi]^2] Log[-((3 (-10 E - 3 \[Pi] + 2 E \[Pi]))/(20 E^2)) - ( 3 Sqrt[100 E^2 + 60 E \[Pi] - 40 E^2 \[Pi] + 9 \[Pi]^2 -  12 E \[Pi]^2])/(20 E^2)])/(E (3 \[Pi] +  10 E (-((3 (-10 E - 3 \[Pi] + 2 E \[Pi]))/(20 E^2)) - (1/( 20 E^2))3 Sqrt[ 100 E^2 + 60 E \[Pi] - 40 E^2 \[Pi] + 9 \[Pi]^2 -  12 E \[Pi]^2]))))`

```
N[%]
```

> `y <= 0.00554749`

```
lot3D[FunctionRange[{-((-1 + t)/(t *\[Lambda] + \[Mu])) + Log[t], 
0 < t < 1}, t, y][[2]], {\[Lambda], 0, 2}, {\[Mu], \[Lambda], 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}]
```

[image]

Edit. The case `\[Mu] >= 1` is considered.